# WEIRDEST ERROR EVER: ASP.NET and Firefox?

Tags: asp.net, firefox

I've always thought that server-side code is unaffected by the browser requesting it, but I've just come across an exception:

I have a button that when clicked, changes the button's CSS class (and those relative to it) and rebinds a GridView with new data. The function is this:

```
Private Sub lbViewUnUsed_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lbViewUnUsed.Click
    lbViewUsed.CssClass = "button small"
    lbViewUnUsed.CssClass = "button small selected"
    BindUsage(UsageBinding.UnUsed)
End Sub
```

In IE, this works perfectly. However, in Firefox, the `BindUsage()` function stops firing midway and nothing gets accomplished at all! In my frustration, I inserted `Debug.Assert()` statements after every line of code in the `BindUsage()` to see what was going on, and sure enough, the function would not go all the way through in Firefox ONLY.

The `BindUsage()` function is this (with the Debug assertions still in):

```
Private Sub BindUsage(ByVal bindWhat As UsageBinding)
    Debug.Assert(False, 1)

    If bindWhat = UsageBinding.Used Then
        gvUsage.DataSource = sUser.GetWordsMarkedWithUsage(True)
        gvUsage.Columns(0).Visible = False 'hide button column'
    Else
        Debug.Assert(False, 2)

        gvUsage.DataSource = sUser.GetWordsMarkedWithUsage(False)
        Debug.Assert(False, 3)

        Dim userInfo As UserAccount.LoginInfo = UserAccount.GetUserLoginInfo
        Debug.Assert(False, 4)

        Dim showUsedButton As Boolean
        Debug.Assert(False, 5)

        showUsedButton = (userInfo.UserName.ToLowerInvariant = sUser.UserName.ToLowerInvariant)
                       Debug.Assert(False, 6)

        gvUsage.Columns(0).Visible = showUsedButton 'show button column'
        Debug.Assert(False, 7)

    End If
    Debug.Assert(False, 8)

    gvUsage.DataBind()
    Debug.Assert(False, 9)

End Sub
```

The above function does not make it past 5 in Firefox. I'm guessing there's some sort of problem with the assignment of the `showUsedButton` variable, but I can't figure out what it would be. Why would this fail only in Firefox, but not in any other browser **especially since this is occurring on the server???**

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting?

Comment: that's the thing, there's no error message... just nothing happens! debug assertions 6+ do not appear!

Comment: also, the CSS assignments from the calling function (the button click) do not actually happen even though they are called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's happening on the server, but you are retrieving data that was generated by the client:

> UserAccount.GetUserLoginInfo

I would review your stored data and see what's different in it based on client application and see how it's handled.

Comment: this fixed it... the case i was checking the user was not logged in so this was returning nothing and i guess making it fail. i needed to check to see if the user was authenticated, which i wasn't doing. thank you for putting me on the right track with this answer!

Comment: Did you fix the fact that you didn't get the details of the error? That sounds like a more serious issue to me, in that next time something bad happens, you'll be stuck with putting Asserts in again.

Comment: @jon - there were no details... i wasn't getting an error message, i was just not receiving the expected behavior. it just plain did nothing.... how would i get those details?

Comment: jon means that instead of just 'nothing' happening, you should instead see an exception thrown. Either as the common red-on-yellow error pages, or during debugging, but not nothing. It's very dangerous when errors are not reported / thrown but just swallowed instead. Are you doing some error handling in the Application_Error method in the global.asax?

Answer (score 3):

Well, it's a bit of a guess, but...

What exactly does `UserAccount.GetUserLoginInfo` do? If I had to guess, it tries to do something browser-specific. For example, it could try and read a cookie from the client? If it does, then my next guess is that `userInfo` or either `userInfo.UserName` is null, thus throwing a NullReferenceException.

It could be that IE accepts cookies, and firefox does not. Hence no error in IE, but only in Firefox.
Again, this is guesswork, I'm not strong in VB.NET and have no idea what that UserAccount class is. Maybe if you'd give use the errormessage, it could mean some more.

Answer (score 1):

Would you definitely spot if any exceptions were being thrown? If not, fix that before you do anything else.

As for why it might be browser-specific:

- If it depends on what data is sent by the browser and how, then clearly the browser can change the behaviour
- I believe ASP.NET renders in a browser-specific way; if your code is touching the rendering logic, it may be behaving differently depending on user agent.